# Couldn't load Flutter project in Xcode

Tags: xcode, flutter

This Question can be repeated, but i have tried with all solutions available on web.

I'm trying to open flutter project in xcode by opening Runner.xcworkspace file from ios folder,
but facing following issue.

1. Couldn't load Runner.xcodeproj
2. Couldn't load Pods.xcodeproj

**P.S  have tried installing Pods**

**P.S Have multiple build flavors**

**EDIT**

Today is i got the error popup with following message
**The project at '/Users/nikhilsawant/StudioProjects/zingoy-flutter/ios/Runner.xcodeproj' cannot be opened because it is in a future Xcode project file format. Adjust the project format using a compatible version of Xcode to allow it to be opened by this version of Xcode**

Anyone have any idea how can i fix this without update xcode, As i don't have any free space.

[image: Screenshot of xcode error]

Comment: Check the flutter SDK path is right or not

Comment: checked , it's alright

Comment: Please also check Flutter_root in xcode

Comment: how i can check that in xcode, can you please help

Comment: Issue is fixed using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49622587/9907043) answer. Thank you.