# Xcode 13 - The project at '/Users/test.xcodeproj' cannot be opened because it is in a future Xcode project file format

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode13, xcode12.5

When opening in Xcode 12.5 a project created with Xcode13, I get this error message:

"The project at '/Users/[...].xcodeproj' cannot be opened because it is in a future Xcode project file format. Adjust the project format using a compatible version of Xcode to allow it to be opened by this version of Xcode."

how am I supposed to adjust the project?

[image: Screenshot of error]

Answer (score 16):

It is easy to change the project format in the Xcode file inspector:

[image: screenshot of the file inspector]

But this is not the whole picture.

Another issue is the missing plist file in Xcode13 created projects.

To make the new project compatible in Xcode 12 you need to add a plist file. The best and quicker solution is to make a new project in Xcode 12 and copy and drop the plist file in the new Xcode13 project. Then make add the necessary changes for your project.

You will need to stop Xcode 13 to generate new `plist` files when you make changes. So return to the project in Xcode13 and set `generate plist file` to no under `packaging` in `Build Settings`:

[image]

I found very helpful information about this in a very good article on [useyourloaf.com](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/xcode-13-missing-info.plist/)

Comment: Where you set the project format? I've been looking for it for an hour

Comment: Took me a moment to find it too. First you select your project on the left then you open the pane on the right and the Project Document will be there.

Comment: I found it, it turned out the project I cloned have some error on it. It is built after the errors are gone.

Comment: It might also be good to remember if it is a workspace to install pods again after updating the format.

Comment: what if I don't have the latest version to open the project? I tried directly modifying pbxproj file (under show package) and setting <compatibilityVersion = "Xcode 13.2"> but still it is giving the same error. I have downloaded the project which is created by XCode 14 while I do have Xcode 13.2 only on my machine.

Comment: @ManishNahar Have you resolved it? 
I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70047054/4933696) to make it working

Comment: @AnuragSharma Yes I was able to resolve it by changing the object version using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69688492/1606492)

Answer (score 6):

Apart from what the other answers suggested, I also had to manually change

```
objectVersion = 53;
```

to

```
objectVersion = 50;
```

in the `*.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` file in order to be able to open a Swift command-line project created with Xcode 14.2 with Xcode 11.3.1.

I also changed

```
LastSwiftUpdateCheck = 1420;
LastUpgradeCheck = 1420;

CreatedOnToolsVersion = 14.2;

CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD = "gnu++20";
```

to

```
LastSwiftUpdateCheck = 1130;
LastUpgradeCheck = 1130;

CreatedOnToolsVersion = 11.3.1;

CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD = "gnu++14";
CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY = "libc++";
```

and now it compiles fine but that didn't affect whether the actual project could be opened with Xcode 11.3.1.

Comment: Worked for xcode 13.2.1 whereas the project i was trying to open built with xcode 14

Answer (score 0):

I solved it selecting the target in the project settings, opening the identity and type window and changing to Xcode 12.0. Then open the project workspace again and done!

Check also the command line tools you are using in Xcode preferences --> locations

[image]
[image]